# Truncar texto e não mostrar caracteres não desejados com rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estou usando a função `truncate` para mostrar parte de um texto, junto a essa função eu adicionei a função `html_safe` para que o texto não mostre caracteres indesejados. Mas quando o texto é maior que o limite que estabeleci, `length: 150`, os caracteres indesejados voltam a aparecer.

Eu gostaria de uma solução para isto, truncar o texto mas que não mostre os caracteres indesejados.

```
<%= truncate(service.description.html_safe, length: 15, )
```

Comment: length: 150 ou 15? Tem um no texto e outro no codigo

Comment: O comportamento é o esperado. Veja: https://repl.it/repls/NovelPopularPercent
O que vc precisa?

Answer (score 0):

A gem [`truncate_html`](https://github.com/ianwhite/truncate_html) talvez resolva teu problema

Exemplo de entrada: `<p>This is <em>my <strong>first</strong> post</em></p>`

Usando a gem: `<%= truncate_html post.title, :length => 15 %>`

Saída: `<p>This is <em>my <strong>fir&hellip;</strong></em></p>`

Comment: Ela trunca o texto assim como esperado, o que ocorre é que quando o texto é maior que o limite imposto pelo length ele retorna caracteres indesejados, caso seja menor que isso ele retorna o texto normalmente!

Answer (score 0):

`<%= truncate(sanitize service.description, length: 15, ) %>`

Exprimenta com o metodo `sanitize(html, options = {})`

Answer (score -1):

vamos lá: A função html_safe é usada para indicar que uma string é segura para ser exibida como HTML. No entanto, ela não afeta a forma como a função truncate funciona. O que pode estar acontecendo é que o texto contém caracteres especiais que não estão sendo tratados corretamente pela função truncate.

Uma solução para isso é usar a função sanitize junto com a função truncate. A função sanitize remove todos os caracteres especiais que não são permitidos em HTML. Aqui está um exemplo de como usar as duas funções juntas:

```
<%= truncate(sanitize(service.description), length: 150) %>
```

Isso deve garantir que apenas texto válido em HTML seja exibido e que quaisquer caracteres indesejados sejam removidos antes de o texto ser truncado. Espero que isso ajude!